# i want to take out words from a string sentence and get this error in c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, substring

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void extractFirstWord(string& sentence, string& word);
void processBlanks(string& sentence);

int main() {
    string sentence, word;
    cout << "Input a sentence: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);

    while (sentence != "") {
          processBlanks(sentence); // removes all blanks from the front of sentence
          if (sentence.length() > 0) { // removing blanks may have made sentence null - cannot extract from a null string
             extractFirstWord(sentence, word); // gets first word from sentence and puts into word
             cout << word << endl; // output one word at a time
          }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void extractFirstWord(string& sentence, string& word)
    {
        int i=0;
        while(sentence[i]!=' ')
        {
            i++;        
        }
        word=sentence.substr(0,i);
        sentence=sentence.substr(i);
}
// extractFirstWord removes the substring of sentence 
// from the beginning to the first space from sentence 
// and stores the same string into word. sentence is
// shortened accordingly.
// Postcondition: sentence is shortened, and word
//                is appropriately the first word in
//                sentence.

void processBlanks(string& sentence)
    {
        int i=0;
        while(sentence[i]==' '){i++;}
        sentence=sentence.substr(i);
    }
```

processBlanks will remove all of the spaces in front of sentence. Postcondition: sentence has no spaces in front of the first word.

i want to take out words from a string sentence and get this error in c++

Error is -> String subscript out of range

Comment: Is it compile time error or run-time error? At which line?

Comment: [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) is very good for extracting space-delimited words, you should look into it.

Comment: As for finding run-time errors, run your program in a debugger.

Comment: Where does the "String subscript out of range" error occurr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `extractFirstWord`, you keep increasing `i` if you haven't yet found a space. However, you might index past the end of the string if it's the last word in the string. Change the `while` condition like so:

```
while(i < sentence.length() && sentence[i]!=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

just consider the case when the input has no spaces, your variable i will increment till length of word and in that case it will be out of range. try to check whether i equals to length of word before the substr() method

Answer (score 0):

use stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::stringstream ss("   first second.   ");

    std::string word;

    ss >> word;

    std::cout << word << std::endl;//first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void extractFirstWord(string& sentence, string& word)
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<sentence.size() && sentence[i]!=' ')  // i should be less than sentence size
    {
        i++;        
    }
    word=sentence.substr(0,i);
    sentence=sentence.substr(i);
```

}